# An interesting problem - an "ugly" familly of distributions - what can we do?

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I've recently encountered an interesting problem. Say, we've got a famility of distributions indexed by a parameter $ \theta$. Say it's a family of descrete distributions (you can also tell me what to do when they are continous...). We know they depend on the parameter $\theta$ but the exact relationship is unknown (it's not given by a mathematical formula). We even know the exact probabilities/distributions! But the relationship between distributions and the $\theta$ is not trivial - for instance we know that the distribution "shifts" to the right in its domain along with the increasing $\theta$ and that's it.

My question is: what can we do with such family? What statistical procedure can we involve? How can we calculate approximate probabilities for new $\theta$? Using some kind of regression? What about a family of continous distributions?

Here is the instance I encountered. I ploted 2 initial distributions (black and red) and the last one (green). We see they, on average, shift to the right as the parameter increases. I'm not completly sure I calculated the probabilities correctly, but it doesn't matter here.[image]

Comment: What question do you want to answer about the populations samples from ugly distributions were sampled from?

Comment: Your plot has the same numbers repeated on the vertical axis. Is this significant? What does it mean?

Comment: To be answerable, this question needs to supply details of *how* you manage to relate values of $\theta$ to their associated discrete probability distributions.

Answer (score 1):

For your family of distributions indexed by $\theta$ if you know the exact probabilities over the sample space then I would argue you do know the functional form.  At the very least you could present the probabilities as a piecewise function.  If you are interested in better understanding the family of distributions indexed by $\theta$ this would not require any sampling.  If you are interested in making inference on, say, the mean of a particular distribution based only on a sample you could use non-parametric or semi-parametric methods.

Comment: I know the distributions only for several $\theta$s and I'd like to know them for new $\theta$.

Comment: For the distributions you are familiar with you could identify functional relationships within the sample space and speculate as to whether these relationships hold for other $\theta$'s.  You could derive a functional form that is a convenient yet perhaps imperfect representation of the distributions you are familiar with and see what the distribution looks like for other $\theta$'s.

Comment: Hehe, yea, but how can I do that? :D We can describe the relationship between $\theta$ and the probabilities only approximately.

Comment: I don't think it would be easy or obvious.  I do think it would involve a lot of "trial and error" attempts and would benefit from having more than three known distributions.  It may also end up being a function of more than just one parameter.  The problem seems so bespoke that it may not be worth the trouble.  The probability distributions we regularly work with were developed because they can address many different problems. You might at well treat each one as a unique "table distribution."